# iPhone SDK: Call method from UIImageViewClass to ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I have this function in my .m ImageView Class file

```
- (UIColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point {
```

How do I call this function from my view controller? I have tried `

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    UIColor* color = [ImageView getPixelColorAtLocation:point];
}`
```

but this gives me a warning stating:  "No known class method for sector 'getPixelColorAtLocation:' (I did import ImageView class files to view controller)

My .h file in ImageView

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface ImageView : UIImageView {
UIColor* lastColor;
//id pickedColorDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor* lastColor;
//@property (nonatomic, retain) id pickedColorDelegate;


- (UIColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point;
- (CGContextRef) createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:(CGImageRef)inImage;
@end
```

My .m file in ImageView

```
    #import "ImageView.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h>
@implementation ImageView

@synthesize lastColor;
//@synthesize pickedColorDelegate;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    if (self.hidden==YES) {
        //color wheel is hidden, so don't handle  this as a color wheel event.
        [[self nextResponder] touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
        return;
    }

    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
   // ColorPickerAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (ColorPickerAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self]; //where image was tapped

    self.lastColor = [self getPixelColorAtLocation:point];
    NSLog(@"color %@",lastColor);
    //[pickedColorDelegate pickedColor:(UIColor*)self.lastColor];
}


- (UIColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point {
    UIColor* color = nil;
    CGImageRef inImage = self.image.CGImage;
    // Create off screen bitmap context to draw the image into. Format ARGB is 4 bytes for each pixel: Alpa, Red, Green, Blue
    CGContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:inImage];
    if (cgctx == NULL) { return nil; /* error */ }

    size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}};

    // Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory
    // allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the
    // raw image data in the specified color space.
    CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, inImage);

    // Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
    // context.
    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
    if (data != NULL) {
        //offset locates the pixel in the data from x,y.
        //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.
        int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
        int alpha =  data[offset];
        int red = data[offset+1];
        int green = data[offset+2];
        int blue = data[offset+3];
        NSLog(@"offset: %i colors: RGB A %i %i %i  %i",offset,red,green,blue,alpha);
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];
    }

    // When finished, release the context
    CGContextRelease(cgctx);
    // Free image data memory for the context
    if (data) { free(data); }

    return color;
}



- (CGContextRef) createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:(CGImageRef) inImage {

    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    // Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
    size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);

    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
    // alpha.
    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    // Use the generic RGB color space.
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    if (colorSpace == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating color space\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    if (bitmapData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
        return NULL;
    }

    // Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits
    // per component. Regardless of what the source image format is
    // (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format
    // specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                     pixelsWide,
                                     pixelsHigh,
                                     8,      // bits per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    if (context == NULL)
    {
        free (bitmapData);
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
    }

    // Make sure and release colorspace before returning
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

    return context;
}
```

Comment: This you class name ImageView or ivar name..... it should be ivar name.

Comment: ImageView* imageView = [[ImageView alloc] init]; UIColor* color = [imageView getPixelColorAtLocation:CGPointMake(100, 100)];

Comment: Depends on where is getPixelColorAtLocation: declared. By the looks of it, it should be in a category of UIImage not UIImageView and import that file in your view controller. And call [ImageView.image getPixelColorAtLocation:point]

Comment: show the code for this method getPixelColorAtLocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Alright, so turns out that when I created the ImageView class it was NOT connected to my target which is why it was not receiving any signals or allowing me to call methods to that class. There goes Apple again making your life a pain! Anyways, to connect the class files to the target, I followed these steps:

- Using XCode 4, in the Project Navigator, select the .m file that contains the class that it is complaining about (ImageView for my case)
- Go to View->Utilities->Show File Inspector
  (this will show the File Inspector to the right, with that .m-file info)
- Open the Target Membership section and make sure that your target is
  selected for this .m-file

Comment: don't think that it's a pain, I am working with 5 targets and more, and it's just normal that you select all the targets you need already in the creation phase :D but nice if it's working :) (by the way, you don't need the way `View->Utilities->Show File Inspector`. Top right, beside the organizer icon, you have the utility views for quick access ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the ImageView in an instance (`with alloc] init]`)
 if you use

```
- (UIColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point
```

or make it static

```
+ (UIColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point
```

Comment: I tried 
ImageView *imageView = [[ImageView alloc] init];
    UIColor *color = [imageView getPixelColorAtLocation:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
and got two errors: (null): (null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ImageView", referenced from:

(null): Objc-class-ref in ViewController.o

(null): Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ImageView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: seems like your ImageView class is corrupted ^^ can you update your question with it (.h and .m) or use http://pastebin.com/ if the code is to long? or try to use it static with a further UIImage as param :) the compiler error definetly is not a reason of this call ;)

Comment: expected that you don't need the `#import "ViewController.h"` in the `ImageView` class, everything seems to work :/ (or do you use the `ViewController` variable later?)

Comment: I got the solution but I cant answer my own question since I have less than 10 reputation! Think u could up the question so I can answer it now! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define your method in `.h` File of your `ImageView` class